# What does 073F:015A meain in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, dosbox

I have been trying to learn Assembly, as I thought it would be something that is fun to learn. I am learning the very basics, and I am just confused as to what something means. I am using DOSBox to use the debug.exe that is not availible in Windows 8 64 bit. I am curious as to what `073F:015A` means. I have this before it:

```
[some previous stuff]
-a 132
073F:0132 jmp 180
073F:0134 db 'Press any key to continue . . .$'
073F:015A
```

I can't tell where I am when this happens, does it mean I didn't jump far enough? (I know I did but it still bothers me because I would like to know where I am.)

Comment: I know that problem when using "debug" as assembler. The only solution was to use some random address (e.g. "jmp 200") and later - when the address is known (15A in your case) - to type "a 132" again and to replace the JMP instruction by a JMP instruction with the correct address.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Yeah, that's what I've been doing after messing around for about an hour, I'm just jumping pretty far ahead so I know it's enough space, then going to that eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

073f is the segment in ram where your program is running. A segment is a block of 64 kb. 0132 is the offset (place) of the jmp command inside the segment 073f. But as a programmer you don't have to know in which segment the program will be started (this depends of where in ram the os finds space).

EDIT: The Offset and the Segment are written in hexadecimal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: Oh okay thank you, but then, what does 015A mean? Does it mean 0151?

Comment: the numbers are hexadecimal. 015A means 346. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal